# covering the code

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I have a login page where I have given page reference to page B. In that page B controller is class B. Inside the standard controller I have given

```
this.username = apexPages.currentpage().getParameters().put('User_Name__c',username );
```

I want to know how to cover this line in test class. Because of this line I am not able to cover the codes its showing like

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to
>   SObject..: line 8, column 1

Can anybody help me with this
Test class:

```
@istest
public class hrmsDetailClasspri_Test{
    static testMethod  void hrmsDetailClasspriMethod(){
        Employee__c emp= new Employee__c( Name__c='name',Joined__c=true,Exit__c='No',User_Name__c='TEST',Password__c='TEST1');
        insert emp;

        leave__c l = new leave__c( Emp_ID__c=emp.id,Leave_Type__c='LOP',Request_Status__c='Approved');
        insert l;

        Payroll__c p = new Payroll__c( Employee__c=emp.id,House_Rent_Allowance__c=1000,Month_and_Year__c=system.today());
        insert p;

        Bills__c b = new Bills__c( Employee_ID__c=emp.id,submitted_date__c=system.today());
        insert b;

        System.AssertNotEquals(Null, emp.id);

        // currentpage.getParameters().put('username', String.valueOf(emp.Id));
        ApexPages.standardcontroller sc=new ApexPages.standardcontroller(emp);
        hrmsDetailClasspri h=new hrmsDetailClasspri(sc);
        apexPages.currentpage().getParameters().put('User_Name__c',TEST);
        h.Request();
        h.submit();
        h.arequest();
        h.Rrequest();
        h.getMonthvalues();
        h.getYearvalues();
        h.getinfo();
        h.save();

        ApexPages.Message[] pageMessages = ApexPages.getMessages();
        System.assertNotEquals(1, pageMessages.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your test class what tried so far?

Comment: @Reshma i have updatted the test class. please see once.

Comment: Are you trying to get parameters from url. If you put parameters to url which do not return any value.

Comment: You should try to set the `'User_Name__c'` parameter on the current page before calling the instantiation of your `hrmsDetailClasspri` class.

Comment: @Reshma ya from url only m getting parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the position of this line

```
apexPages.currentpage().getParameters().put('User_Name__c','TEST');
```

to

```
apexPages.currentpage().getParameters().put('User_Name__c','test@test.com');
hrmsDetailClasspri h=new hrmsDetailClasspri(sc);
```

and if you are doing any search based on this username then you might need to provide a genuine value here

```
apexPages.currentpage().getParameters().put('User_Name__c',userInfo.getUsername());
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the current page context in your unit test method so the controller gets the page parameter when its running in the test context

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.YourPageBHere;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```